# Flex Application.application.setStyle() with PopUpManager cause Flash plugin to crash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

Why does Flash crash when I use the setStyle() function with the PopUpManager?  The module works when "Application.application.setStyle()" is taken out.  Thanks in advance!

```
var popup:SurveyQuestionsPopup = new SurveyQuestionsPopup();
            Application.application.setStyle('modalTransparencyColor','black');
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup,Application.application as DisplayObject,true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);
            popup.dataProvider = arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a bug in the Flex framework because you're trying to apply something to an instance that's not yet fully initialized or even on the stage.  I can't know for sure since you haven't specified which version of the Flex SDK you're working with.  Try using a `validateNow()` call and moving the `setStyle` call to after the popup has been created (shown below).  Keep in mind that calling setStyle is an expensive procedure and should be avoided whenever possible.  Generally, there are few reasons it should ever need to be called.

```
var popup:SurveyQuestionsPopup = new SurveyQuestionsPopup();
PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup,Application.application as DisplayObject,true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);
popup.dataProvider = arr;
popup.validateNow();
Application.application.setStyle('modalTransparencyColor','black');
```